# How to configure external url for OWA for SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, office-web-apps, owa

The SharePoint farm and the Office Web App farm is configured for the internal url, but it hasn't been configured for the external url.

How do I configure the external URL now?

should I be configuring this on the OWA server or the web server?

I changed the zone to External-HTTPS but it still isn't showing the preview.    The thing is I have an alternate access mapping done for external clients, when they access it via the AAM, they cant see the preview feature. the preview shows the error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to run it on the SharePoint Servers.

Run the following xommand

```
[Set-SPWOPIZone][1] -Zone "external-https"
```

You have to pick the correct Zone, here are the supported Zone

- Internal-HTTP
- Internal-HTTPS
- External-HTTP
- External-HTTPS

[Configure Office Web Apps for SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431687.aspx)

Comment: I have updated my answer with a screengrab of the error.  I have changed the zone to External- Https, but I  still get the same error.   I have an Internal URL and an External URL, hence two zones as well, the default zone or the internal zone which has a url XYZ.com and an external URL for the Intranet zone done as a Alternate Access Map a ABC.com  .... I can see the preview in XYZ.com,  but I cannot see it on ABC.com .    I need to configure the zone with a URL. How do I go about and configure Two zones with Two URLs.

Comment: what it returns Get-SPWOPIZone

Comment: it used to return "Internal - https" ,   now that I changed it to External, it returns "External - https"

Comment: in which zone of AAM of your url? i think it should be external zone

Comment: what are the out put from both command Get-SPWOPIZone & Get-SPWOPIBinding? should be same

Comment: The zone for the AAM is set to Intranet. The Get-SPWOPIBinding doesn't return anything.

Comment: can you change AAM settings to external zone and then run  Set-SPWOPIZone -Zone "external-https"

Comment: If I change the zone now, would it effect anything else?

Comment: it may be, do you have test farm? or any other web app where u can test it...I am hesitate to do it in Production while people active on it

Comment: The zone's available for AAM are "Default, internet, intranet, extranet and custom" and it is set to Intranet at the moment.

Comment: do you have test envrinoment?

Comment: one more thing, isyour OWA url accessible from externally? when you setup your using this command i.e. New-OfficeWebAppsFarm -InternalUrl "https://server.corp.contoso.com" -ExternalUrl "https://server.external.contoso.com"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50100/discussion-between-waqas-sarwar-mcse-and-codeabaddon).